# Neo4j: Poor performance when doing a "join" on a chain of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Below is a diagram to give you a general idea of how my graph is structured:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbn0J.png

It simply contains :Person nodes that are attached to a :PersonType. Each :Person can express zero or more opinions. These opinions are either genuine opinions (:Opinion) or opinions borrowed from someone else (:OpinionProxy). An :OpinionProxy or an :Opinion has always one and only one :EXPRESSED relation.

I wrote a cypher query to answer the following question:
*Give me all the opinions expressed by all the "Cool Guys", and for each opinion the chain of people that this opinion went through*.

Example with the sample data:

```
+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| person             | opinion             | influence           |
+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| "Dan"              | o4                  | "Dan"               |
+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| "Dan"              | o3                  | "Dan", "Jim", "Jay" |
+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| "Bob"              | ...                 | ...                 |
+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Here is a query that look for all the opinions of all the "Cool Guys":

```
MATCH 
    (:PersonType {name: "Cool Guys"})<-[:OF_TYPE]-(p:Person)-[:EXPRESSES]->(o), 
    opath=(o)-[:REFERENCES*0..]->(op:Opinion)
RETURN p.name AS person, op AS opinion, opath
```

So far so good. Now the intricate part comes from trying to return the chain of :Person rather than a chain of :OpinionProxy-[*0..]->:Opinion. Here is my attempt:

```
MATCH 
    (:PersonType {name: "Cool Guys"})<-[:OF_TYPE]-(p:Person)-[:EXPRESSES]->(o), 
    opath=(o)-[:REFERENCES*0..]->(op:Opinion)
MATCH (x)<-[:EXPRESSES]-(opAuthor:Person)
WHERE x IN nodes(opath)
RETURN p.name AS person, op AS opinion, collect(opAuthor) AS influence
```

This query returns exactly what I want, except it **runs extremely slow**.

To give you an idea, in my test environment I have about 3000 :Person (including 70 "Cool Guys"), 3000 :Opinion and 3000 :OpinionProxy. Response time:

- Query 1: completes in about 200ms
- Query 2: completes in about 3200ms

That's an order of magnitude increase just to "join" the :Person associated with an :Opinion or :OpinionProxy. For Neo4j that's just one pointer to follow and I did not expect to see such a performance gap between those two queries.

Is there anything wrong with my second query? How can I optimize it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the WITH statement between the two match statements. I think now the first MATCH will run over and over again.

```
MATCH 
    (:PersonType {name: "Cool Guys"})<-[:OF_TYPE]-(p:Person)-[:EXPRESSES]->(o), 
    opath=(o)-[:REFERENCES*0..]->(op:Opinion)
WITH opath,p,op
MATCH (x)<-[:EXPRESSES]-(opAuthor:Person)
WHERE x IN nodes(opath)
RETURN p.name AS person, op AS opinion, collect(opAuthor) AS influence
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. While your query still returns the correct dataset, it runs equally slowly.

Comment: Can you generate a execution plan for your query? Run your query in the neo4-shell prefaced with "profile" like this: profile MATCH (:PersonType ...

Comment: Here is the profile for the original query and your version: http://pastebin.com/x6T2A7MQ . Again thanks a lot for looking into this!